# iOS SDK : Push Issue Creation rather than present 'modally'

Tags: ios, objective-c, zendesk

Using the Zendesk SDK for iOS an issue creation view controller can be presented as follows:

```
    [ZDKRequests showRequestCreationWithNavController:self.navigationController];
```

What is the easiest / highest level of abstraction for pushing the same view controller, rather than presenting it 'modally' ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `ZDKCreateRequestViewController` is not designed to be pushed but you can `push` it by calling

```
ZDKCreateRequestViewController *viewController = [[ZDKCreateRequestViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

But you will need to remove the the left `navBarButton` as it won't work because it is trying to dismiss modally. You can do this by setting `viewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil` before you push and this will then allow the view controller to generate a `navBarButton` that will **pop** the view controller.